# Can I override colon operator in Lua?

Tags: lua, operator-keyword, overriding

Lua is using colon operator (`:`) as instance method calling. Can I override this operator for another purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. There is no such thing as colon operator- it's pure syntactic sugar.

```
obj:func() == obj.func(obj)
```

This does, however, mean that you can override the dot operator used here and the function call operator of the return value.